# Como receber valor de uma variável de outra Classe

Tags: ios, mvc, swift

Tenho uma variável na classe *Classe1* e quero utilizar essa variável em   uma função  na classe *Classe2*

a Tela1 tem como seu controle a *Classe1* e tela2 tem como controle a *Classe2*

ao ser chamada a tela2, a *Classe2* executará uma função que tem como parâmetro a variável da *Classe1*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi através do **prepareForSegue** como sugerido pelo @JadsonMedeiros
aprendi através desse [site do James Leist](http://jamesleist.com/ios-swift-passing-data-between-viewcontrollers/)

1) Criei uma **segue**  selecionando o *botão na tela* e segurando a tecla CTRL, arrastei a tela2

1.1) No *StoryBoard*, selecionei a segue (seta que liga as telas) e no *Attributes Inspector*, no campo *Identifier* coloquei *NomeDaSegue*

2) na classe1 para passar a variável, adicionei a função

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "NomeDaSegue" {
            var svc = segue.destinationViewController as! Classe2

            svc.variavelDaClasse2_1 = variavelDaclasse1_1
            svc.variavelDaClasse2_2 = variaveldaClasse1_2.text
        }
    }
```

3) na Classe2 onde vou utilizar a variável recuperada

```
// dados da Classe1, não podem receber valores
    var variavelDaClasse2_1 : Int!
    var variavelDaClasse2_2 : String!


 print(variavelDaClasse2_2)
 print(variavelDaClasse2_1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Existem várias formas de se fazer isso, acredito que a forma mais fácil é passando o valor via atributo.

Declare na ViewController1 como atributo o valor que você quer passar.

```
var numeroAleatorio = 4
```

Na ViewController 2, crie um atributo que receba o valor da ViewController1.

```
var viewController1: ViewController!
```

Como nesse caso você NÃO vai inicializar a variável, é NECESSÁRIO que você utilize o operador ! que significa que a variável é opcional. Caso você não utilize, o Swift vai pedir que você inicialize a variável o que não é sua intenção, já que ela já foi iniciada na ViewController1.

O tipo desta variável tem que ser a classe da sua ViewController1.

Agora, vamos exibir na tela sua ViewController 2 da ViewController1.

```
let v2 = ViewController2()
v2.viewController1 = self

self.presentViewController(v2, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Note que em

```
v2.viewController1 = self
```

você está apontando o valor do atributo viewController1 que você criou na sua ViewController2 para sua primeira view.

Com o ponteiro pra sua primeira variável, fica extremamente fácil acessar QUALQUER atributo da variável da primeira view.

```
NSLog("%d", viewController1.numeroAleatorio)
```

Se você começar a ter mais duas views, talvez seja interessante você pesquisar sobre Singleton.

Recomendo que você também estude formas de persistir suas informações como CoreData e o NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Obrigado Carl, vou testar aqui.. referente ao CoreData optei por não salvar o valor porque ele é temporário, o que vai ser salvo é o resultado da função que esta no View2

Comment: deu erro    
  _v2.viewController1 = self_

que v2 nao pode receber o tio v1

Comment: você definiu v1 como UIViewController ou como ViewController? O tipo de v2.viewController tem que ser o tipo da sua primeira view.

Comment: Desculpa Carl, como estou começando no IOS acabei me confundindo, as classes são do tipo UIViewController.. vou reformular a pergunta

Comment: Qual o nome da sua primeira view? Me passa a linha que você declarou o atributo viewController1

Comment: editei a pergunta novamente

Comment: Fábio, procura por **prepareForSegue**, é bemmmmmmm mais fácil.

Comment: @JadsonMedeiros muito obrigado, no começo foi meio confuso os materiais que achei, mas nesse link da pra entender muito bem http://jamesleist.com/ios-swift-passing-data-between-viewcontrollers/